# Supremum Axiom of $S = \{a+b\sqrt{2}: a,b \in Q\}$

Tags: analysis

Let:

$$S = \{a+b\sqrt{2}: a,b \in Q\}.$$

It can be shown that $S$ ordered field. Dose the Supremum Axiom hold in $S$? Why? (with proof please)

Comment: That's two unrelated questions. You should edit this post to contain only one of them and post the other separately.

Comment: You should also explain what you have tried, instead of asking a homework question with proof.

Comment: I don't know how to start !!

Comment: I know the Supremum Axiom does not hold in Q. However, since S in not bounded, does the Supremum Axiom even apply? I I have the same homework problem and would really appreciate any help!

Comment: You should start by writing down what the supremum axiom is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Regard $S$ as an additive subgroup of the reals. Now an additive subgroup of the reals is of one of two types,

- either it is discrete (that is, of the form $\{ n \alpha : n \in \mathbf{Z}\}$ for some $\alpha$),
- or it is dense in $\mathbf{R}$.

**Follow-up** Now $S$ is not discrete. In fact if $1, \sqrt{2}$ are integer multiples of a common $\alpha \in \mathbf{R}$, then it follows that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, a contradiction. So $S$ is dense in $\mathbf{R}$. Were $S$ to contains the suprema of each of its (nonempty, bounded from above) subsets, then it would be the whole of $\mathbf{R}$, but $S$ is countable, while $\mathbf{R}$ is not.

Answer (score 3):

Let $R=\{r \in S|r^2<3\}$  $R$ is bounded but you should be able to show that for any element of $R$ there is a larger one. Think of Newton's method of finding $\sqrt 3$